# Binding NULL in JAVA for MySQL PreparedStatment?

Tags: java, mysql, data-binding, prepared-statement

MySQL uses "IS NULL" instead of "NULL" so how do i bind variable to achieve the same ?

Right now i tried with this

```
selectStmt.setNull( 2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
```

when i printed "java.sql.Types.VARCHAR" shows value = 12 ? If so how does this set " IS NULL" in preparedstatment ?

**MORE DETAILS:**

i.e I am interested in querying (MySQL) for null if i have string = " " in input. So logic goes like this,

```
Connection c = SQLCon.connect();
PreparedStatement selectStmt = c.prepareStatement( "select * from "
                                    + TableName
                                    + " where P = ? AND M = ? AND PR = ? AND DR = ? " );


if ( P.trim().equals( "" ) ) 
{
   selectStmt.setNull( 1, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
} else 
{
   selectStmt.setString( 1, P );
}

if ( M.trim().equals( "" ) ) 
{
   selectStmt.setNull( 2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR );
} else 
{
   selectStmt.setString( 2, M );
}
```

Please advice

Comment: That is indeed how you set the second bound variable to null if it's a VARCHAR column.  What is your question?

Comment: @PaulTomblin : it is varchar column but query is not fetching me the result i need.

Comment: Don't use an empty string for null.  Use a null for null.  They are two totally different animals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to match a column in a where clause that might be null with a parameter that might be null, you actually need to bind it twice, because in SQL a null doesn't equal anything else, even another null.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from foo where (? is null and bar is null) or (bar = ?)");
col = 1;
setVarchar(stmt, col++, var);
setVarchar(stmt, col++, var);

void setVarchar(PreparedStatement stmt, int col, String var)
{
  if (var == null)
    stmt.setNull(col, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
  else
    stmt.setString(col, var);
}
```

Comment: You can also use WHERE IFNULL(?,-1)=IFNULL(bar,-1).  Replace -1 with a suitable value that shouldn't be present in the data or the bind variable.

Answer (score 2):

It seems odd, but you do:

```
if (variable == null) {
  selectStmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
} else {
  ...
}
```

the reason behind this is because `NULL` is a value in a database, and not having a value is `null` in Java.  Occasionally, you need to differentiate between getting back a `NULL` from the database as opposed to getting back nothing from the database.

Comment: Then check the basics.  Perhaps you have the wrong `java.sql.Types.***` datatype, you have dropped or lost your database connection, you don't have a selectStmt with two parameters, or you didn't create a selectStmt.  Trust me, "setNull" is the right way to store a "NULL" in the database, and on the java side `variable == null` is the right way to check if a variable holds no reference.

Answer (score 0):

it's an xml input and on UI user see blank for NULL and hence to send blank as input

```
if ( P.trim().equals( "" ) )
  {
    sql += "P IS NULL";
  }
   else
  {
    sql += "P = ?";
  }

PreparedStatement selectStmt = c.prepareStatement( sql );

int i = 1;
// used to prevent index out of range issues

// Binding values for non-null strings ONLY
 if ( !(P.trim().equals( "" )) )
  {
    selectStmt.setString( i, P );
  i++;
  }
```