# How to Insert Null Value into a Column which already have a Value using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null, sql-update

Lets just say I have a row which looks like this:

```
ID(Long), serialNumber(Long)
1           123
```

I want to update this row with `(1,null)`.
How can I do it? So far from my research, I save that on Update, but it ignores null values.

Comment: `update yourtable set serialNumber = NULL`

Comment: I doing the update from sql statment using Java,
the update ignores null values.

Comment: Are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961486/binding-null-in-java-for-mysql-preparedstatment ?

Comment: no, it is not look related

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update column with null value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870540/how-to-update-column-with-null-value)

Comment: Rigel1121: I saw this issue, did not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. It works:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    
serialNumber = null
WHERE  ID = 1;
```

Comment: I am doing insert with a flag to the statement of "update if exists"
so I am not calling directly to update statement.

Comment: You can't Insert a value into a column which already have a value. Unless, what you're trying to say is to Insert another row on which if serialNumber is exist to any of the row, then the serialNumber of a newly inserted row will now be equal to null. Is that so?